# Wordpress behind a Reverse Proxy: Trailing Slash and Search Engine Access

Tags: wordpress, reverse-proxy

Looking for some help with using Wordpress behind a reverse proxy.   Got two issues.

The setup is like this.

We host the Wordpress site at: [www.myblog.com](http://www.myblog.com)
The Wordpress version is 5.6.4.
The client reverse proxies the site with IIS at: [www.ourdomain.com/blog/](http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/)

Trailing Slashes

Wordpress will redirect requests from it's root.   So if a page request is missing a trailing slash, it will 404.   So for example:

Request: https://www.ourdomain.com/blog/myarticle

Redirects to: https://www.ourdomain.com/myarticle which is a 404.   It should stay at: https://www.ourdomain.com/blog/myarticle.
It currently only works with a trailing slash.

Indexing for Search Engines

What is the best way to prevent search engines from indexing the site at: [www.myblog.com](http://www.myblog.com) but still allow indexing at:
[www.ourdomain.com/blog/](http://www.ourdomain.com/blog/)

Comment: Did you end up finding solution for this?